# What's the better way to check if input is string?

Tags: c, string, validation

I'm making a program in which i ask for the username name, and i'd like to only accept strings with valid characters only (alphabetic).

I found that i can either use

```
    do{
       //since scanf returns the number of currectly input
       if(scanf("%s", &name) == 1)
           break;
       else printf("Please enter a valid name.\n);
    }while(1);
```

or

```
    do{
       check = 0;
       scanf("%s", &name);
       for(i=0; i<strlen(name; i++){
          //since isalpha() returns != 0 if it's a letter
          if(isalpha(name[i]) == 0){
             printf("Invalid character. Please enter a valid name.\n");
             check = 1;
             break;
          }
       }
    }while(check == 1);
```

But i'm not sure if any of those work, and what would be better to check if there isn't anything except alphabetic letters.
Also though about making all input letters (after this verification) on lower case and make the first letter upper case with

```
    //all to lower except the first letter
    for(i=1; i<strlen(name); i++){
       name[i] = tolower(name[i]);
    }
    //first letter to upper
    name[0] = toupper(name[i]);
    x=1;
    while(name[x] != '\0'){
       //if the letter before is a white space, even the first letter, it should place the first letter of a name upper
       if(name[x-1] == ' ')
          name[x] = toupper(name[x]);
       x++;
    }
```

Would this work?

Comment: You already wrote the code.  Try it.

Comment: @rost0031 I asked: a or b? you answered: yes.

Comment: The first version will not work. `scanf` `%s` formatter matches "a sequence of non-white-space characters". Thus it will match both alpha and non-alpha character.

Comment: @AlanAu is there a way to use fgets and check if the number of arguments is correct?
If it founds 1 non-alpha character it's suposed to say it's not correct and to re-enter. Doesn't matter if they are all correct with 1 wrong or all wrong.

Comment: when calling any of the scanf() family of function, with a '%s' input/conversion parameter, always include a length modifier, so the user does not overrun the input buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at each option.

**First option:**

```
do {
   //since scanf returns the number of currectly input
   if(scanf("%s", &name) == 1)
       break;
   else printf("Please enter a valid name.\n");
} while(1);
```

This won't quite work the way you expect. First off, what exactly is `name`? I'm almost sure that you want `scanf("%s", name)` instead (`name` instead of `&name`), unless you declared it as `char name;`, which would be catastrophic anyway.

Anyway, the problem I see with this approach is that you don't really validate the string. Read the man page section about `%s`:

> s - Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to character array that is  long  enough  to hold 
>   the  input  sequence  and  the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is
>   added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the
>   maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

Nothing says that the string is composed of alphabetic characters only.

**Second option:**

```
do{
   check = 0;
   scanf("%s", &name);
   for(i=0; i<strlen(name); i++){
      //since isalpha() returns != 0 if it's a letter
      if(isalpha(name[i]) == 0){
         printf("Invalid character. Please enter a valid name.\n");
         check = 1;
         break;
      }
   }
}while(check == 1);
```

Again, you probably want `name` rather than `&name`. You also shouldn't be calling `strlen()` in the `for` loop condition, because it's inefficient (`strlen()` is O(n)). A smart compiler may optimize it away, but it's hard for the compiler to know when it is safe to do so. Just call `strlen()` before the loop and store the result in a variable.

`isalpha()` expects an integer as an argument, which is expected to be either `EOF` or an `unsigned char` converted to `int`. Again, you don't show the declaration for `name`, but assuming that it is a character array, you should cast `name[i]` to `unsigned char` before calling `isalpha()`, so that you don't get any sign extension surprises:

```
if (isalpha((unsigned char) name[i]) == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

In fact, gcc nowadays will most likely give you a warning if you call any of the `ctype` family macros / functions with a plain `char`. The macros are deliberately written in such a way that a warning is shown, *precisely* because this is a common mistake. It is implementation-defined whether a  plain `char` is signed or unsigned. You would get problems in a platform with signed chars because of sign extension (this is because typically, things like `isalpha()` are implemented using lookup tables, and extending the sign yields a negative number that would index the lookup table with a negative index - Oops!)

Other than this, this approach seems ok to me.

**A third, maybe better option:**

Since you mentioned `fgets()`, I think you could do this easily by combining `fgets()` with `sscanf()`. First, you read a line with `fgets()`. Then, you use `sscanf()` to match a string consisting of only characters in the range `[a-zA-Z]`. This can be done with the format specifier `%[a-zA-Z]s`. Then, you just have to check if this matched the entire line. Here's a working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    static char buf[512];
    static char name[512];

    int is_valid = 0;

    while (!is_valid) {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

        size_t line_len = strlen(buf);
        if (line_len > 0 && buf[line_len-1] == '\n') {
            buf[line_len-1] = '\0';
            line_len--;
        }

        int n = 0;
        if (sscanf(buf, " %[a-zA-Z] %n", name, &n) == 1 && buf[n] == '\0') {
            is_valid = 1;
        } else {
            printf("Please enter a valid name.\n");
        }

    }

    printf("Name: %s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure your buffers are large enough; this code is vulnerable to buffer overflow for arbitrarily long names / lines.

Now let's see the code to make the first letter upper case:

```
//all to lower except the first letter
for(i=1; i<strlen(name); i++){
   name[i] = tolower(name[i]);
}
//first letter to upper
name[0] = toupper(name[i]);
x=1;
while(name[x] != '\0'){
   //if the letter before is a white space, even the first letter, it should place the first letter of a name upper
   if(name[x-1] == ' ')
      name[x] = toupper(name[x]);
   x++;
}
```

Again, remove `strlen()` from the loop condition. `toupper()` and `tolower()` also expect an `int` as an argument representing either `EOF` or an `unsigned char` converted to `int`. You should cast it to `unsigned char` to avoid problems with possible sign extension, as I said earlier with the other example.

This is wrong:

```
//first letter to upper
name[0] = toupper(name[i]);
```

It should be:

```
//first letter to upper
name[0] = toupper(name[0]);
```

(The argument to `toupper()` is `name[0]`, not `name[i]`).

Finally, this is useless:

```
x=1;
while(name[x] != '\0'){
   //if the letter before is a white space, even the first letter, it should place the first letter of a name upper
   if(name[x-1] == ' ')
      name[x] = toupper(name[x]);
   x++;
}
```

`%s` will never give you a string with whitespaces (refer to the manpage quote I pasted above).

Comment: I only thought about that later. First of all, char* name. Second, let's change scanf to fgets.
Can i still use the second option? (with the corrections you made).
The part of upper and lower, that line was a typo, and would the second part be correct now?

Comment: @AndréAlmeida See updated answer. I added a 3rd option that uses both `fgets()` and `sscanf()`. I think it's the easiest way to do what you want.

Comment: @AndréAlmeida Also, remember that `char *name;` is not enough; if this is how you declared `name`, the code won't work. You need to either declare it as an array or allocate memory.

Comment: I have a scruct, and it has char name[MAX_CHAR]; with #define MAX_CHAR 100 before the struct.

Comment: `" %[a-zA-Z]s"` --> `" %[a-zA-Z]"`  No need for `s`.

Comment: `buf[strlen(name)] == '\0')` is curious - trying to detect leading spaces?

Comment: @chux Hah, the idea was to make sure everything in the line is part of the name, to prevent things like `anamewithnumbers123456` from being seen as correct by matching `anamewithnumbers` and leaving the rest (which I assumes it not what the OP wants). Your comment made me realize that this won't work if the line has leading spaces. Maybe I should replace it with `%n` instead and use that to validate that everything was consumed.

Comment: Many valid approaches.  I do favor appending a `" %n"` to the sscanf [format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30517350/2410359) as simple tests that 1) `n` was changed (scanning completed) and 2) `buf[n] == 0` (no more left).

Comment: @chux Thanks for the insight. I agree that `%n` is definitely a wise choice. I updated my answer.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves With the "buf[n] == '\0' " it doesn't work. And i don't really understand what it's suposed to do. Why would buf[1] == '\0' ?

Comment: @AndréAlmeida Hum, I tested it and it looked ok. Can you show the input where it fails? `buf[n] == '\0'` ensures that the whole line is consumed, i.e., things like `name123` are interpreted as invalid, whereas `name` is successful. Without `buf[n] == '\0'`, `name123` would be successfully matched as `name` and leave `123` unconsumed.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves any valid input that doesn't have a whitespace in the end. i believe it's because it checks for buf[1] were it should check for buf[0]

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves nevermind, it's not that. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @AndréAlmeida it doesn't check `buf[0]`. It checks the position of the line where `sscanf()` stopped processing. Note that `n` is modified by `sscanf()` because of the `%n` format specifier.

Answer (score 3):

`if(scanf("%s", &name)` reads in all non-white-space, not just letters, into `name` and does not return if input is only `"\n"`.

`if(isalpha(name[i]) == 0){` loop is not bad, but `scanf("%s", &name)` still does not return if input is only `"\n"` or just white-space.

`for(i=1; i<strlen(name); i++) name[i] = tolower(name[i])` works to make all following letters lower case, but if inefficient as code repeatedly calculates the string length.

Separate reading data and parsing data.  Use `fgets()` to read the data and various code to test the data for correctness.

```
char buf[200];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

int n = 0;
// Skip leading white-space
// Look for A-Z, a-z or space  (like a space between first & last)
// Skip white-space like \n
// Save into 'n' the current scan position
sscanf(buf, " %*[A-Za-z ] %n", &n);
if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') Success();  // @user3121023
```

Should code need to rid `buf` of a potential trailing `"\n"`, suggest:

```
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: If you do, compare to `strlen(buf) - 1`, as `fgets` includes the trialing `'\n'` in `buf`.

Comment: @David The `" "` in `" %n"` will skip over a potential final `'\n'`.  `strlen(buf) - 1` does not always index a trailing `'\n"` as 1) last line in file may not have `'\n'` 2) embedded `'\0'` may occur.

Comment: (sigh...) Alas, point well taken, but I took the initial comment to ask if he should check `strlen (buf)` to determine if `n` contained the entire contents of what was read, indicating that `strlen` would be taken prior to `sscanf` as `strlen(buf)` against `n`. In that case, I wanted to make sure he understood that when checking against the `strlen` of `buf` he understood that there would be an additional `newline` in `buf`.  ( I know, clear as mud... `:p`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want your name to have only characters a through z or A through Z then you could use this function

```
//Returns 1 if non alphabetic character is found, 0 otherwise
int NonAlphaCharsFound(char *name)
{
    int FoundNonChar = 0;
    int i, nameLength;

    nameLength = strlen(name);

    for(i = 0; i < nameLength; i++)
    {
        if((name[i] >= 'a' && name[i] <= 'z') || (name[i] >= 'A' && name[i] <= 'Z') || name[i] == ' ')
        {
            //do nothing if it's an alphabect character
            //name[i] == ' ' is to allow for spaces if you want spaces in the name
        }
        else
        {
            FoundNonChar = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return FoundNonChar;
}
```